# How to turn url into XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I'm trying to use this URL...

http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?Symbol=T

It acts like a XML but it isn't in the right format, I want to be able to use it to display it in XML form...

this is my code right now

```
protected void btnGetResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XPathNavigator nav;
    XmlDocument myXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();
    String stockQuote = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?Symbol=T" + txtInfo.Text;
    myXMLDocument.Load(stockQuote);

    // Create a navigator to query with XPath.
    nav = myXMLDocument.CreateNavigator();
    nav.MoveToRoot();
    nav.MoveToFirstChild();

    do
    {
        //Find the first element.
        if (nav.NodeType == XPathNodeType.Element)
        {
            //Move to the first child.
            nav.MoveToFirstChild();

            //Loop through all the children.
            do
            {
                //Display the data.
                txtResults.Text = txtResults.Text + nav.Name + " - " + nav.Value + Environment.NewLine;
            } while (nav.MoveToNext());
        }
    } while (nav.MoveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source of the response you receive. The content (everything with the rootnode) is no XML. The tags are HTML entities: `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Loading that straight into you XmlDocument will treat all the content you are after as simple text.

The following example downloads the online resource, replaces the HTML entities with tags and reloads the XML document, which is then accessible by XPath.

```
string url = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx/GetQuote?Symbol=T";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);

string actualXml = doc.OuterXml;
actualXml = actualXml.Replace("&lt;", "<");
actualXml = actualXml.Replace("&gt;", ">");
doc.LoadXml(actualXml);
```

I haven't considered the second part of your example source code. But I guess having a proper XML document will be the first step.